# My debounce from lodash is not working with input and Reacttsx

Tags: html, reactjs, debouncing, tsx

I added the lodash debounce to my input and i want to use it. I checked with console.logs the methode but it never enters the debounce part.

```
const debounce = require('lodash/debounce');

filterFeed(event: any){
    // event.preventDefault()
    event.persist();
    debounce(() => {
        let searchString = event.target.value;
        let unfilteredFeed: any = this.unfilteredFeed;
        let filteredFeed: any = unfilteredFeed.filter(el => el.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()));
        this.setState({ input: searchString, feed: filteredFeed, filter: true })
     }, 300);

}

 <input className="basic-slide" id="name" type="text" value={this.state.input} placeholder="Event..." onChange={ this.filterFeed.bind(this)} /><label >Suche</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole function you pass to `onChange` in debounce and save its reference:

```
filterFeed = (event: any) => {
  // event.preventDefault()
  event.persist();
  let searchString = event.target.value;
  let unfilteredFeed: any = this.unfilteredFeed;
  let filteredFeed: any = unfilteredFeed.filter(el => el.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()));
  this.setState({
    input: searchString,
    feed: filteredFeed,
    filter: true
  })
}

debouncedFilterFeed = debounce(this.filterFeed, 300);


<input className="basic-slide" id="name" type="text" value={this.state.input} placeholder="Event..." onChange={this.debouncedFilterFeed} /><label >Suche</label>
```

Comment: Ok i did this but then i get this error. "This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property target on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()."

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, and you do have `event.persist();` in the code?

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things i found my solution:

```
filterFeed= debounce((text) =>{
    let searchString = text;
    let unfilteredFeed: any = this.unfilteredFeed;
    let filteredFeed: any = unfilteredFeed.filter(el => el.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()));
    this.setState({ input: searchString, feed: filteredFeed, filter: true })
}, 20)

<input className="basic-slide" id="name" type="text" value={this.state.input} placeholder="Event..." onChange={e  => this.filterFeed(e.target.value)} /><label >Suche</label>
```

Comment: hehe yes exactly the same as i posted :D

Comment: One note: notice that the user experience with this functionality is really poor, because nothing appears in the input field, during the "delay".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround:

```
filterFeed = (value) => {//Pass the value, not the event   
    let searchString = value
    let unfilteredFeed = this.unfilteredFeed;
    let filteredFeed = unfilteredFeed.filter(el => el.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
    this.setState({
      input: searchString,
      feed: filteredFeed,
      filter: true
    })
  }
```

And your JSX:

```
<input className="basic-slide" id="name" type="text" value={this.state.input} placeholder="Event..." onChange={(e)=>{
          const value = e.target.value;
          this.debouncedFilterFeed(value)
          }} /><label >Suche</label>
```